# Does this system of congruences have a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have the following congruence equation system:

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c} x \equiv 7 \pmod{7} \\ x \equiv 4 \pmod{12} \\ x \equiv 16 \pmod{21} \\\end{array} \right. $$

I understand that:

$$x\equiv a (mod w) \wedge \ x \equiv b (mod k)$$ has a solution iff $$gcd(w,k)| (b-a)$$

So I operated and found:

$$gcd(7,12) = 1 | (7-4) \rightarrow 1 | 3 : true$$
$$gcd(12,21) = 3 | (16-4) \rightarrow 3 | 12 : true$$
$$gcd(7,21) = 7 | (16-7) \rightarrow 9 | 7 : false$$

And concluded that the system does not have a solution, however, it appears to be a wrong procedure according to my teacher, and I would like to know the correct approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first congruence means that $x$ is divisible by $7$ , but the third means $x=21k+16$ for some integer $k$ and this is not divisible by $7$. Hence the system has no solution.

Comment: Correct, reducing the first and third mod their moduli gcd $= 7\,$ yields $\bmod 7\!:\,\ 7\equiv x\equiv 16,\,$ which is a contradiction, cf. linked CRT solvability criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third congruence gives you that $x=21k+16$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This also then means that

$$x=21k+16\equiv2\pmod{7},$$

which contradicts the first congruence. Thus the system has no solution.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).